# How to get Data From two Different Tables of database in Codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, frameworks

Database contain two tables.
1st table contain teacher name.and the 2nd Table contain Teacher ID and Courses Detail.
I want to Get Teacher name from the 1st table and Teacher ID from 2nd table.
I tried this code but didnt work

```
 public function searchfors($id)
{
 $s=$this->db->from('course','staff')->where('stuentid',$id)->get();
 return $s->result();
}
```

Or anyother option.?

Comment: give your table name & clear Is there any relation between two table?

Comment: yeah ,,i am using search option to get teacher id ,after putting that id user can see the teacher name and his courses that are in different tables

Comment: have you tried `$this->db->join()`?

Comment: nops ,i konw thiss in php but don't know how it works in codeignitor

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function searchfors($id)
{
 $s = $this->db->select('s.teacher_name,c.teacher_id')->from('staff c')->join('course c','c.teacher_id = s.id')->where('c.stuentid',$id)->get();
 return $s->result();
}
```

assuming your teacher table name is `stuff` & another table name is `course` & there is a relation via column `teacher_id` (from course table) and `id` (from stuff table)